# How to trigger Shift + Key in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I need to execute the Shift + Tab by command when I click on Arrow Up, but I have no idea how to do this.

I need your help ^^

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you expect from your software with the Shift-Tab key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//API function declaration to simulate keystrokes GLOBAL EXTERNAL FUNCTION
subroutine keybd_event(uint bVk,uint bScan,long dwFlags,long dwExtraInfo ) library 'user32.dll'


public function integer of_presskey (integer ai_key);//Calls an API function to simulate a key press
keybd_event(ai_key,0,0,0)   
return 1
end function

public function integer of_releasekey (integer ai_key);//Calls an API function to simulate a key release
keybd_event(ai_key,0,2,0)   
return 1
end function


//Put the following in the KEY event if available.  Otherwise create a custom event using //the Event ID pbm_keydown for regular objects or the Event ID pbm_dwnkey for DataWindows.
CONSTANT INT VK_SHIFT = 16      //Keycode for the SHIFT key
CONSTANT INT VK_TAB = 09        //Keycode for the TAB key

//Simulates a TAB keystroke when the DOWN ARROW OR ENTER is pushed as long
//as it isn't on the last column or the last row.  Kills the DOWN ARROW
//keypress
if ((key = KeyDownArrow! OR key = KeyEnter!)) then
    ibl_noenter = false
    of_presskey(VK_TAB)
    of_releasekey(VK_TAB)
    Yield()
    return 1

//Simulates a SHIFT + TAB keystroke when the UP ARROW is pushed.
//Kills the UP ARROW keypress
elseif (key = KeyUpArrow!) then

    ibl_noenter = true

    //Simulating SHIFT + TAB Keystroke
    of_presskey(VK_SHIFT)
    of_presskey(VK_TAB)
    of_releasekey(VK_SHIFT)
    of_releasekey(VK_TAB)
    Yield()

//Allows a TAB keypress to go through
elseif (key = KeyTab!) then

    return 0

end if
```